# I confuse bout this sign != what does that mean?

Tags: syntax, language-agnostic

anyone please can you answer my curious and confuse about function of this sign in android syntax `!=` ?

Comment: `!=` not equal to.  This is common operator in most of programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means not equals to.

```
0!=1
```

will return true

```
1!=1
```

will return false.
it is the same as 
    not(1==1)

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for the usual programming sign `!=`, it's commonly used to imply "not equal to". As in:
 `if (counter != 4) -> raise flag`, here, the hypothetical flag would be raised only if the counter was different from 4. Depending on the language it can imply inequality on the value contained on the object or inequality of objects (as in Java).